# PHP, XHTML and ampersands

Tags: php, xhtml

How do I replace ampersands in a url from `& > &amp;`

I use some rss feeds witch has URL containing `&` should I use

```
$link = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $link);
```

or there are other options?

Comment: -1. Seriously : http://www.google.com/search?q=php+replace+ampersand&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlentities). It replaces not just `&` but also `"`, `<`, `>`, and `'` (only if *quote_style* parameter is set to `ENT_QUOTES`) that all need to be replaced with appropriate character references.